# How to handle relationships from API in react js?

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, axios

I want to post data in rest API, which contains foreign key fields. How can I get the options given to select as given in API

[image: REST API]

Here **Category** and **Seller** are foreign key fields. And I want these Option to display in my frontend React JS App. how can I get these?

Answer (score 0):

This page coming from rest api. You should fetch data via rest views. Such as;

```
class CategoryViewSet(viewset.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Category.objects.all()
    permission_classes = []
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer
```

and give an url for this viewset. After that you can get the categories from rest api.